# Find path relativity with regex

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement something similiar to `path.relative(...)` from NodeJS in Rust, but this time without porting the actual code from NodeJS. I've this regex from the `regex` crate:

```
static PATH_SEPARATOR: Lazy<Regex> = lazy_regex!(r"[/\\]");
```

So I want to find the relative path from a path *a* to a path *b*. Both paths are absolute and have all `..`, `.` sequences and `//` resolved. For example, `relative_path("/a/b", "/a/c")` should yield `"../c"`.

The problem is, what logic can I use? I tried the following, but I suppose something will go wrong if `from_parts` and `to_parts` have different lengths?

```
pub fn relative_path(from_path: &str, to_path: &str) -> String {
    let mut r = Vec::<String>::new();

    let from_parts: Vec<String> = PATH_SEPARATOR.split(resolve_single_path(from_path).as_ref()).map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect();
    let to_parts: Vec<String> = PATH_SEPARATOR.split(resolve_single_path(to_path).as_ref()).map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect();

    let l1 = from_parts.len();
    let l2 = to_parts.len();

    for i in 0..l1 {
        if from_parts[i] != to_parts[i] {
            r.push("..".to_owned());
        }
        r.push(to_parts[i].clone());
    }

    if l1 > l2 {
        for _i in l2..l1 {
            r.push("..".to_owned());
        }
    } else {
        for i in l1..l2 {
            r.push(to_parts[i].clone());
        }
    }

    let r = r.join("/");
    let r = r.trim();
    if r.is_empty() { ".".to_owned() } else { r.to_owned() }
}
```

It's not producing what I expect.

The `resolve_single_path()` function is already implemented for reference:

```
fn resolve_single_path(path: &str) -> String {
    let mut r = Vec::<String>::new();
    for p in PATH_SEPARATOR.split(path) {
        if p == "." {
            continue;
        } else if p == ".." {
            if !r.is_empty() {
                r.remove(r.len() - 1);
            }
        } else if !p.is_empty() {
            r.push(p.to_owned());
        }
    }
    r.join("/")
}
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend using [`Path::components`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.components) instead of splitting your own paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the actual algo, I think what you have right now would fail a number of cases.

Before coding, I'd *think*. Or you can try TDD.

But here's a simple step-by-step that you should consider:

1. You can throw away all path components that `from` and `to` share *at the beginning*. (Not later! Because there might be separate subdirectories with shared names! Like `projects/project1/src` and `projects/project2/src`. You definitely don't want to throw away that `src`.)
2. Now that you have thrown away all the parts where `from` and `to` are already the same, you know the first item is where the paths first diverge.
3. So maybe I'm naive or my coffee isn't kicking in just yet but why can't we just create a `..` for the relative path for each of the components in `from` and then just add each of the components of `to`?

Example of that:

`from = projects/project1/subproject2/src`

`to = projects/project2/src`

Step 1, throw away the common element:

`from = project1/subproject2/src`

`to = project2/src`

Step 2: Create a `..` for each component of `from`, so that

`rel = ../../../`

Step 3: Append `to`, so that

`rel = ../../../project2/src`

Seems about right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cadolphs, I've got this:

```rust
pub fn relative(from_path: &str, to_path: &str) -> String {
    if ![from_path.to_owned(), to_path.to_owned()].iter().all(|path| STARTS_WITH_PATH_SEPARATOR.is_match(path)) {
        panic!("file_paths::relative() requires absolute paths as arguments");
    }

    let mut r = Vec::<String>::new();

    // since the given paths are absolute, resolve_one() returns
    // something like "/foo/bar" and resolves ".." and "."

    let mut from_parts: Vec<String> = PATH_SEPARATOR.split(resolve_one(from_path).as_ref()).map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect();
    let mut to_parts: Vec<String> = PATH_SEPARATOR.split(resolve_one(to_path).as_ref()).map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect();

    // given each path is absolute, each one can contain an empty
    // initial second part. in that case, remove the empty string,
    // since the path `"/"` is previously split into a `vec!["", ""]`.
    let from_parts = remove_empty(&mut from_parts);
    let to_parts = remove_empty(&mut to_parts);

    fn remove_empty(parts: &mut Vec<String>) -> &mut Vec<String> {
        if parts[1].is_empty() {
            parts.remove(1);
        }
        parts
    }

    let mut common_indices = Vec::<usize>::new();

    for i in 0..usize::min(from_parts.len(), to_parts.len()) {
        if from_parts[i] != to_parts[i] {
            break;
        }
        common_indices.push(i);
    }
    for i in common_indices.iter().rev() {
        let j = common_indices[*i];
        from_parts.remove(j);
        to_parts.remove(j);
    }
    r.append(&mut Vec::from_iter((0..from_parts.len()).map(|_| "..".to_owned())));
    r.append(&mut to_parts.clone());

    let r = r.join("/");
    let r = r.trim_start().to_owned();
    if r.ends_with('/') { r[..r.len() - 1].to_owned() } else { r }
}
```

Tests:

```
assert_eq!("", relative("/a/b", "/a/b"));
assert_eq!("c", relative("/a/b", "/a/b/c"));
assert_eq!("../../c/d", relative("/a/b/c", "/a/c/d"));
assert_eq!("..", relative("/a/b/c", "/a/b"));
assert_eq!("../..", relative("/a/b/c", "/a"));
assert_eq!("..", relative("/a", "/"));
assert_eq!("a", relative("/", "/a"));
assert_eq!("../../c/d", relative("/a/b", "/c/d"));
assert_eq!("../c", relative("/a/b", "/a/c"));
```